# Problem: $\sigma$-algebras and $\sigma \mathcal{C}$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

I have started to read about $\sigma$-algebras, p-systems, d-systems, and measurable spaces but am having some difficulty piecing things together.

The first exercise has already given me some trouble conceptually, hence this post. How should I think about this following?

#### Problem

Let $E$ be a set and let $\mathcal{C} = \{ A,B,C \}$ be a partition of $E$. List the elements of $\sigma \mathcal{C}$.

**Ideas**

$\sigma \mathcal{C}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$, so might this just be $\mathcal{E} = \{\mathcal{C}, \emptyset\}$? We have that $\mathcal{C} \cup \emptyset = \mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{E}$ (closed under countable unions). We have $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{E} \implies E\setminus \mathcal{C} = \text{ ??? } \subseteq \mathcal{E}$.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}$ is a set of sets, but you are treating it like a set, which I don't think is correct. Looks to me like the exercise is asking  you to actually list out all the $2^3$ sets in $\sigma\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: I was thinking something along the same lines: $\{ \{A,B,C\}, \emptyset \}$ doesn't seem to be closed under complements. I was thinking that the answer might be short or something simple, but $\sigma \mathcal{C} = \{ \emptyset, \{A, B\}, \{B, C\}, \{A\}, \{B\}, \{C\}, \{A,B,C\} \}$ fits the bill for a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathcal{C}$. I guess the only thing I am stuck up on is understanding why this $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest one containing $\mathcal{C}$ and, generally, how to tell if a particular $\sigma$-algebra is the smallest containing some given set $\mathcal{C}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathcal C$ is a collection of sets. $\{ \mathcal{C},\emptyset\}$ is not the same as $\mathcal C \cup \{\emptyset\}$. $C \cup \emptyset=C$ is true for **any** set $C$, not only $\mathcal C$: this is not using any properties of a $\sigma$-algebra. So I feel you have not understood the meaning of "closed under countable unions". $\mathcal C\in\mathcal \sigma \mathcal C$ is wrong; it should be $\mathcal C\subset\mathcal \sigma \mathcal C$.

A simpler example as a hint: If $A\subset\Omega$ and
$$ \mathscr A = \{A\}$$
then
$$ \sigma \mathscr A = \{\emptyset, A,A^c,\Omega\}.$$
Note that this is not a 'list'
$$ \emptyset, \{A\},A^c,\Omega$$
Instead $\sigma \mathscr A$ is an actual set.

And $\mathscr A$ is **not** an element of $\sigma\mathscr A$.

Proof: Any $\sigma$-algebra on a set $\Omega$ must have $\emptyset$ and $\Omega$ as its elements; As $\mathscr A \subset \sigma\mathscr A$, we must have $A\in\sigma \mathscr A$. As $\sigma \mathscr A$ is closed under complements, $A^c\in \sigma \mathscr A$. So the above four elements are forced by the definition. As it is easily checked to be a $\sigma$-algebra, it is the smallest such.

The proof for $\mathcal C$ is much the same.

Comment: My apologies with the mistyping of 'in' vs. 'subset'. In my mind, I say "$\mathcal{C}$ in $\mathcal{E}$" and typed \in by mistake. So, I believe I understand "closed under countable unions". But, your answer clarifies the definition of $\sigma \mathcal{C}$. To be more precise and to make certain I've learned what I need to learn I would have, for the original problem, $\sigma \mathcal{C} = \{\emptyset, E, A, B, C, B\cup C, A \cup B, A\cup C \}$? Also, will it always be the case individual sets in $\mathcal{C}$ are also in the set $\sigma \mathcal{C}$? Please prune the content of this comment.

Comment: @rodeo_flagellum yes, that's the right answer!

Comment: Nice, you have furthered my understanding of mathematics and for that I am grateful. I wish you the best @Calvin Khor